# Groupby all columns except for one and sum on that last column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet with around 17 columns. I want to groupby the first 16 columns and sum up the last column (which is quantity).

[image]

Looking at the picture, the row with "104039" and the row below should be grouped together as the first 16 rows are the same.

I have written the codes below to do the groupby:

```
cols=[*report]
report=report.groupby(cols[:-1],as_index=False,sort=False)[cols[:-1]].sum()
```

However, the end result removes most of the rows instead of grouping by. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which rows are removed? I suppose it has only grouped the rows by the first 16 columns. Have you tried: `report=report.groupby(cols[:-1],as_index=False,sort=False).sum()`?

Comment: My bad I forgot to copy the last part of the code, the actual code is the one you posted

Comment: your last line isn't exactly the same as mine though. with `[cols[:-1]]` you're excluding the last column (Quantity, the one of interest). BTW it's easier to help you if you include your table as code, not as an image.